# Colocar variável no seletor jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Vi alguns posts sobre o assunto, porem não adiantou.

o problema é o seguinte:

**CSS:**

```
.spanClass{
 display: none;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" name="nome" id="nome">
<span class="spanClass"></span>
```

**jQuery:**

```
        $("#nome").on("keypress", function(){
            mask($(this), maskName);
        });

        function mask(o,f){
            v_obj = o;
            v_fun = f;
            setTimeout("execMask()",1)
        }

    function execMask(){
        var id = v_obj.attr('id'); // aqui eu pego o id 
        console.log(typeof(id)); // result: string
        v_obj.val(v_fun(v_obj.val(),id)); // aqui eu passo o valor do campo do meu input e o id dele.
    }


//nesta função eu recebo o regex, alvo(valor do input), uma msg, e o id(Sim já verifiquei no console, todos esses valores chegam até minha função alertMsg.

function alertMsg(regex,alvo,msg,id){
    if(regex.test(alvo)){
        $("#"+id).text(msg).fadeIn(); // esse comando não funciona.
    } else {
        $('#'+id).text("").fadeOut(); // esse comando não funciona.
    }
}
```

Alguem sabe me dizer pq não estou conseguindo colocar uma variável no seletor jQuery?

OBS: o ultimo comando não apresenta nenhum erro no console, ele simplesmente não executa, se eu colocar manualmente o id ele funciona.

OBJETIVO: Ao colocar caracteres NÃO permitidos, exibe uma msg abaixo do input.

Answer (score 2):

**SOLUÇÃO:**

**CSS:**

```
.spanClass{
 display: none;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" name="nome" id="nome">
<span id="nomeSpan" class="spanClass"></span>
```

**jQuery:**

```
function mask(o,f){
    v_obj = o;
    v_fun = f;
    setTimeout("execMask()",1)
}

function execMask(){
    var id = v_obj.attr('id');
    v_obj.val(v_fun(v_obj.val(),id));
}

function replaceName(){
    $("#nome").on("keypress", function(){
        mask($(this), maskName);
    });
}

function alertMsg(regex,alvo,msg,id){
    if(regex.test(alvo)){
        $("#"+id+"Span").text(msg).fadeIn();
    } else {
        $('#'+id+"Span").text("").fadeOut();
    }
}
```

ERRO DO TÓPICO ACIMA:

Estava pegando o id do próprio input e querendo exibir uma mensagem no SPAN com ele, alterei apenas essa linha no **html**, `<span id="nomeSpan" class="spanClass"></span>`, e esta linha no **jQuery**  `$("#"+id+"Span").text(msg).fadeIn();`, assim eu consigo exibir a mensagem abaixo do input que teve a condição do if retornada false.